# centering logo in fixed navigation

Tags: css, navigation

I am currently using floats in order to place my logo in the center of my fixed navigation menu. The issue I'm facing currently is that the items I've floated to the right are displaying in reverse order.

How do I use text-align to achieve desired result and still maintain a fixed navigation header?

current code:

```
<img src="img/logo.png" class="logo" />

<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#section1" class="item1">A</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section2" class="item2">B</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section3" class="item3">C</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section4" class="item4">D</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section5" class="item5">E</a></li>
   <li><a href="#section6" class="item6">F</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0, 100px, 0, 0;
  margin: 10px, 100px, 35px, 0 ;
  position: fixed;
  height: 6em;
  background: transparent;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
header .logo {
  display: block;
  height: 110px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
header ul {
  margin: -85px auto 0 auto;
  height: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

header li:nth-child(1), header li:nth-child(2), header li:nth-child(3){
  float: left;
}

header li:nth-child(4), header li:nth-child(5), header li:nth-child(6){
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: There are many solutions to this but it depends on whether you can change the HTML or not.

Comment: first, fix your css code, have a few errors, for example, in padding and margins, no use (,) to separate dimentions, (use padding: 0 100px 0 0), position relative is not necesary in .logo object, and finally why are you using text-indent in you logo?

Comment: I can change it, yes. I just need need logo in the middle of menu items, and for the items to be listed in the correct order. thanks!

Comment: thanks, for pointing these things out xzegga, but as it stands, those little errors are not the reason I'm asking for help. Please read my post again if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most obvious solution, break the menu into two and put the logo in the middle...then float each menu as required.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: .5em;
}
nav {
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav left">
    <li><a href="#section1" class="item1">A</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#section2" class="item2">B</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#section3" class="item3">C</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <a href="#" class="logo">Logo</a>

  <ul class="nav right">
    <li><a href="#section4" class="item4">D</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#section5" class="item5">E</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#section6" class="item6">F</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Of course, you may want all the items bunched together..in which case you don't need the floats at all

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/9bms9kvd/3/)

Then again, there's this one I like (not mine) which is even better : [**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/wolfcry911/pen/HyLdg)

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! Am wondering what you mean by bunching it together?

Comment: See the JSFiddle Demo

Comment: actually, that creates another issue. I need the navigation to be fixed. How can I resolve that?

Comment: You can set position fixed on the `nav` element.. it shouldn't affect anything....but that's a different question.

Comment: That's because you haven't set a width on the nav - https://jsfiddle.net/tzsLorLh/1/

Comment: Yes! just noticed that now. Thank you again!